# Coefficient problem in algebra

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $ x^{8} $ in the expansion of  $ (1+x^2-x^3)^{9} $ 
I know the problem is simple if we use multinomial theorem and I got an answer  $ 378 $  using it. Can someone check it and also provide a shorter method if possible.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  Multinomial theorem is the shortest proof here, the point being only 4 $x^2$s or one $x^2$ and two $x^3$ (the rest being $1$s) can give a product $x^8$.  So you can almost just write down the answer
$$
\binom{9}{5,4,0}+\binom{9}{6,1,2}(-1)^2=126+252=378.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way though ?

Comment: At precalc level?  Expanding this is laborious but it does work.  Same goes with repeated use of binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using Binomial Theorem

the coefficient of $x^8$ in $\displaystyle((1+x^2)-x^3)^9$

$=$ the coefficient of $x^8$ in $\displaystyle\binom90(1+x^2)^9+$ the coefficient of $x^2$ in $\displaystyle\binom92(1+x^2)^7$

$\displaystyle=\binom94+\binom92\binom71$

$\displaystyle=126+36\cdot7=?$

Answer (score 0):

You may reduce it to using the binomial theorem only as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}[x^8](1+x^2-x^3)^{9}
& = & [x^8](1+x^2(x-1))^{9} \\
& = & [x^8]\sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{9}{k}x^{2k}(x-1)^k\\
& = & [x^8]\sum_{k=\color{blue}{3}}^{\color{blue}{4}}\binom{9}{k}x^{2k}(x-1)^k\\
& = & \binom{9}{3}[x^2](x-1)^3 + \binom{9}{4}[x^0](x-1)^4\\
& = & 3\binom{9}{3} + \binom{9}{4}\\
& = & 378\\
\end{eqnarray*}